# dbt (data build tool) jinja modules - 'dict object' has no attritute 're'

Tags: dbt

According to DBT's docs on modules to use within jinja functions - https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/modules - `modules.re` should be available. However, there is this macro I am working with:

```
{% macro camel_to_snake_case(camel_case_string) -%}

{{ modules.re.sub('([A-Z][a-z]|[A-Z]*[0-9]+)', '_\\1', modules.re.sub('([A-Z]+[A-Z]([a-z]|$))', '_\\1', camel_case_string)) | trim('_') | lower() }}

{%- endmacro %}
```

and whenever a script is run that uses this macro, i receive the error:

```
Running with dbt=0.17.0
Encountered an error:
Compilation Error in model model_using_macro (models/model_using_macro.sql)
  'dict object' has no attribute 're'
```

Do I need to install something in order to access the `modules.re` function? Maybe the base dbt I have installed doesn't have this `modules` at all? Perhaps there is a way I can check the output for `modules` to see why `re` is missing, and what else might be available / missing? I'm not sure why else this error could be happening?

Answer (score 3):

Try upgrading dbt, `re` was added in 0.19.0 ([source](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/releases/tag/v0.19.0))

Comment: Getting a similar error , but for datediff or datesprint macros in dbt utils

09:41:17    'dict object' has no attribute 'datediff'. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. Check for typos and/or install package dependencies with "dbt deps".
Tried upgrading dbt to v1.4 , but in vain -- testing out different ideas, but any help is appreciated as datediff, datespine both still do exist as macros

Comment: @pravin While it may seem similar, this is a distinct question, I encourage you to ask it separately to try and get an answer.

Comment: Yup agreed, done - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75528600/dbt-datediff-dict-object-compilation-errors