# Dbt datediff - dict object compilation errors

Tags: dbt, dbt-utils

Recently, upgraded my dbt to v1.3 and facing some issues with a few macros but a new compilation error keeps coming for datediff or datespine , which is not working out

Error message:

```
09:29:41    'dict object' has no attribute 'datediff'. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. Check for typos and/or install package dependencies with "dbt deps".
```

I’m trying to fix this so that my sessionization code works out
Source: segment/segment_web_page_views__sessionized.sql at main · dbt-labs/segment · GitHub

My packages look like this :
packages:

- package: dbt-labs/dbt_utils
  version: “1.0.0”

**What I’ve already tried**

- Tested a few new macros like datespine, but the same error shows up. Also the macro does exist in dbt-utils too - so not sure what’s causing it.
  https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/blob/main/macros/sql/date_spine.sql
- Upgraded to dbt v1.4, but same error persists

Code part that causes errors: -

```
diffed AS (
    --calculates `period_of_inactivity`.
    SELECT
        *,
        {{ dbt_utils.datediff(
            'previous_tstamp',
            'timestamp',
            'second'
        ) }} AS period_of_inactivity
    FROM
        lagged
```

Would appreciate any directional help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of dbt 1.3 and dbt_utils 1.0, [cross-database macros](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/cross-database-macros) have moved out of dbt_utils and into the main adapter code ([source](https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/migration/versions/upgrading-to-dbt-utils-v1.0#functionality-now-native-to-dbt-core)), so you can just `dbt.datediff()`and it will work.

I can't answer the problem you're having with date_spine without knowing what code you're using to call it, but hopefully this helps get you unblocked!